# Generators of $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fundamental-groups, projective-space, spheres

There's a proof in [Tom Dieck](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/diecktop.pdf) p.$436$ of the [Borsuk-Ulam Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem) which is the following:

[image]

What I don't get here is why taking a generic path $v$ from $x$ to $-x$ we know that composed with the orbit map generates $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^n)$ and $u = Fv$ generates $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^{n-1})?$

Is there any way to see the latter algebraically or there is a simple geometric idea behind it?

Any help hint or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware that $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ for $n \geq 2$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Yes I am.

Comment: All you have to do then is show that $p_n\circ v$ is a non-contractible loop in $\mathbb{RP}^n$. You can do this by observing that $v$ is a lift of $p_n\circ v$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese What about $Fv$?

Comment: @jacopoburelli It's essentially the same. Since $F$ is an odd map, $Fv$ is a path from $F(x)$ to $-F(x)$ (connecting a pair of antipodal points in $S^{n-1}$). Using the same argument (lifting property), $Fv$ is a non-trivial element in $\pi_1(\Bbb RP^{n-1})$.

Comment: @Kevin.S Yes thanks, the argument seems to work. What I don't understand is whether every path from $-x$ to $x$ can be taken, since here you are only proving it for particular ones. The books seems to say that works for any. Thanks in advance.